# Fetching object error in union

Tags: php, mysql

I have sql query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT      op.reference_no, op.eight_percent, op.ten_percent, 
                    op.date, op.claim, op.orders_history_id, 
                    oh.one_product_price, oh.quantity


        FROM        order_promotion op

        LEFT JOIN   orders_history oh 
        ON          oh.id = op.orders_history_id

        WHERE       oh.customer_id = $member_id

        UNION ALL       SELECT type, receiveable, null AS a, null AS b, null AS c, 
                        null AS d, null AS e, null AS f 
                        FROM infimoney_transfer
```

I am able to echo data inside the table tag here `<td>".$objek->receiveable."</td>` It echo the record from the table.

However when I tried to check if the record is exist:

```
$saldo = $mysqli->query($sql);
if(!$saldo){ printf("Errormessage: %s\n", $mysqli->error); die(); }

if ($saldo->num_rows > 0) {
   while($objek = $saldo->fetch_object()) {

    $thq = $objek->receiveable; // line 50
    var_dump($objek->receiveable); // line 51
    echo $objek->receiveable; // line 52
    if ($thq) 
                {
                    $i++;
                    echo "<tr>
                            <td>".$objek->type."</td>
                            <td>".$objek->receiveable."</td> // line 59. 
                            <td>".$i."</td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td></td>
                            <td>Cinta</td>
                         </tr>";
                }
```

It come with the following error: `Undefined property: stdClass::$receiveable` in line 50, 51, 52. While in the line 59 it echo the record without an error.

What is the problem?

Comment: What do you see if you var_dump $objek?

Comment: @Sherlock Nothing but the error message: `Undefined property: stdClass::$receiveable` on that line.

Comment: No, just var_dump the entire object, not just that property.

Comment: @Sherlock `var_dump($objek);` `object(stdClass)#6 (8) { ["reference_no"]=> string(8) "cashback" ["eight_percent"]=> string(5) "39900" ["ten_percent"]=> NULL ["date"]=> NULL ["claim"]=> NULL ["orders_history_id"]=> NULL ["one_product_price"]=> NULL `["quantity"]=> NULL }

Comment: it doesn't print the union select in the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
while($objek = $saldo->fetch_object()) {
    if (isset($objek->receiveable)) 
        {
           $thq = $objek->receiveable; // line 50
           var_dump($objek->receiveable); // line 51
           echo $objek->receiveable; // line 52
           $i++;
           echo "<tr>
                     <td>".$objek->type."</td>
                     <td>".$objek->receiveable."</td> // line 59. 
                     <td>".$i."</td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td></td>
                     <td>Cinta</td>
                 </tr>";
         }
```